# Boot physically-installed Linux in VMware Workstation on Windows 10

Tags: linux, windows, virtual-machine, vmware

I have a Windows 10 that I use daily, with VMware WS 14 installed on it. I also have another Ubuntu system installed on another hard drive on the same computer and it has been used only a few times.

My Windows and Ubuntu do not interfere with each other, they reside on two completely separated drives. The second hard drive contains everything the Ubuntu needs, including EFI System Partition and the root file system, and correctly configured (I can boot from that hard drive directly).

Now I want to boot that Ubuntu in VMware on the Windows, is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The information is covered in the VMware article
[Using Physical Disks in a Virtual Machine](http://pubs.vmware.com/ws6_ace2/ws/ws_disk_add_raw.html).

> - When prompted to specify the type of virtual machine configuration, select Custom.
> - On the Select a Disk page, select Use a physical disk, and specify whether you want to use individual partitions or the entire disk.   If
>     you use individual partitions, only the partitions you select will be
>     accessible to the virtual machine. The other partitions might be
>     “visible” to the guest operating system, but it is not possible to
>     mount, access, or format them.

[image: image1]

[image]